# getting back feature extraction result in a csv

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, feature-extraction, training-data

I have a csv dataset and had applied feature extraction such as wavelet, kurtosis so that later do machine learning. I am new to python and machine learning so not able to understand how to get back the feature extracted csv file.

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNH5g.png)

I am unable to get back the feature extracted csv file. what should I do?

This is the code which i wrote.
I want that i get back features.csv as a result but it is not writing into it.

```
path = r"C:\Users\DELL PC\Desktop\Msc Project\MSc project\dataset"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    print(file)

lowfiles = files(os.path.join(path, r"Training data\LOW"))
highfiles = files(os.path.join(path, r"Training data\HIGH"))

mypath = 'Training-Data/'
csvfile = "Features/features.csv"

with open(csvfile, "a") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(names) 

    subfolder =  files[counter][1]
    tag = files[counter][1] 
    data_path = mypath + subfolder +'/'+files[counter][0]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please check how to format appropriately your code blocks (we did it for you this time)...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `pandas` module. It provides a lot of I/O functions, powerful data processing, and much more.

Loading a CSV file from disk is as simple as:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/infile.csv')
```

where `df` is a `DataFrame`, which is pandas' main data structure.

Writing a `DataFrame` to disk as a CSV file is also just one line:

```
df.to_csv('outfile.csv')
```

This [link provides documentation to pandas I/O](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html).